# my dynamically added movieclips have a name of "instance XX"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, actionscript, movieclip

There are a couple things going on here that I dont fully understand.  I have created a custom class that extends MovieClip to give some custom properties and create a geometric shape inside of the created MovieClip

```
package com.hyatt
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.geom.*;
public class mapPin extends MovieClip
{

    public var spirit:String;
    public var callName:String;
    public var hotelName:String;
    public var city:String;
    public var s:String;
    public var zip:String;
    public var country:String;
    public var brand:String;
    public var featured:Boolean;
    public var horizon:Boolean;
    private var _mc1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function mapPin(_brand:String)
    {
        brand = _brand;
        switch (_brand)
        {
            case "Andaz":
                    pinCircle(0xff0000);
                    break;
            case "Grand Hyatt":
                    pinCircle(0x0000ff);
                    break;
            case "Hyatt":
                    pinCircle(0x4600f0);
                    break;
        }
    }

    private function pinCircle(color:uint):void
    {
        _mc1.graphics.beginFill(color);
        _mc1.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,20);
        this.addChild(_mc1);
        _mc1.graphics.endFill();
    }
}

}
```

Then I'm adding an couple instances of the mapPin class to a container movieclip on my stage and adding an event listener to that container clip.

```
var myTest1:mapPin = new mapPin("Andaz");
myTest1.brand = "Andaz";
container_mc.addChild(myTest1);
myTest1.name = "myTest1" //this is added purely for testing the "instance xx", same result
myTest.x = 100;
myTest.y = 100;

var myTest2:mapPin = new mapPin("Hyatt");
container_mc.addChild(myTest2);
myTest2.brand = "Hyatt";
myTest2.x = 400;
myTest2.y = 400;

container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pinClicked);
```

finally I'm trying to be able to access the properties (the only one set thusfar is "brand") of the mapPin that is clicked.

```
function pinClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target.name); // traces "instance xx" instead of "myTest1"
trace(e.target.brand); // traces "undefined"
}
```

I can add the mapPin instances, and adjust their x and y though i cannot reference the custom class properties like "brand" and their name becomes a generic instance name.  What am I missing?  There are going to be upwards of 500 of these items added and I want to be able to pull information from them based upon a users click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to see your mapPin class to be sure, but I think that the DisplayObject that is dispatching the event, is a child of mapPin.

To fix this, inside your mapPin class constructor add this line :

```
mouseChildren = false;
```

That will specify that children shouldn't receive clicks/dispatch mouse events.

Comment: You can also look at `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`. currentTarget is the most recent object to dispatch an event and target is the object that originally dispatched it. More times than not, e.currentTarget is the correct object you want.

Comment: That is true, but in this case the listener is attached to `container_mc`, so `e.currentTarget` is the `container_mc`, not the `mapPin`.

Answer (score 0):

> currentTarget is the most recent object to dispatch an event and target is the object that originally dispatched it

It's not. AS3 doc says :

> currentTarget : 
>   The object that is actively processing the Event object with an event listener. For example, if a user clicks an OK button, the current target could be the node containing that button or one of its ancestors that has registered an event listener for that event.
>
> target : The event target. This property contains the target node. For example, if a user clicks an OK button, the target node is the display list node containing that button.